Como adicionar framework iOS en app Flutter?
Estoy tratando de adicionar un framework IOS en una aplicacion Flutter y no logro generar la ruta correcta, de la carpeta del framework, a pesar de adicionarlo directamente desde el Xcode, el mensaje que me genera es el siguiente:
(lldb) dyld[1361]: Library not loaded:
'@rpath/FRAMEWORK.framework/FRAMEWORK'
Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/36E437E3-73F7-45A5-B0E7-44A2C843CDF7/Runner.app/Runner'
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/FRAMEWORK.framework/FRAMEWORK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/36E437E3-73F7-45A5-B0E7-44A2C843CDF7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FRAMEWORK.framework/FRAMEWORK' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FRAMEWORK.framework/FRAMEWORK' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/36E437E3-73F7-45A5-B0E7-44A2C843CDF7/Runner.app/Frameworks/FRAMEWORK.framework/FRAMEWORK' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/FRAMEWORK.framework/FRAMEWORK' (no such file)
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
La ruta del framework es: appFlutter/iOS/Frameworks/FRAMEWORK.framework
Alguien que me pueda guiar al respecto.
Seguir los pasos de la documentación flutter
